# How Can I choose count the data in one column based on other column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframe as below:

```
df1 = DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(10, size=2)})
df2 = DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(10, size=100)})
```

There is two numbers in df1, and I want to count the two numbers'  amount in df2. The answer is in the right of df1['a'].

I use for in, but there is a error:Length of values does not match length of ' 'index.

Anyone can tell me how to slove this question?

I use df2['a'].isin(df1['a']).sum(), but it give me the result that the amount of two numbers together.

I want the result like:

```
No  Amount
8   3
1   2
```

instead of :

```
No  Amount
8   5
1   5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df2.a.value_counts().reindex(df1.a)
Out[369]: 
a
4    11
5     5
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Add `sum`

```
df2.a.value_counts().reindex(df1.a).sum()
Out[370]: 16
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but there still has a problem, the two amount is same, one is correct one is wrong

Comment: @yuchenhuang check the first line of my code..

Comment: it perfectly solves my problem, REALLY REALLY thanks for your time!!!!!!

Comment: @yuchenhuang if that is the case , can you accept it?

Comment: I am trying to used in my real case, but as least I know the function, I think I can solve this question finally. Thanks and thanks, this question just spend my whole afternoon time !

Comment: @yuchenhuang yw you can click the check mark

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
In [22]: df2['a'].isin(df1['a']).sum()
Out[22]: 18
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use your method, but the result is not correct. The problem is that two amount is same, one is correct but another is not correct and the number is same.